# Prove that if $A\sim B$ then $\mathscr{P}(A)\sim \mathscr{P}(B)$. Is my proof correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I think I understand the way it should be proved, I think I get the idea, but I'm unsure about writing it.

That is my proof.

Since $A \sim B$ there is a function $f:A\to B$ that is one-to-one and onto. We can use this function to make the function $g:\mathscr{P}(A)\to\mathscr{P}(B)$. For any $X\subseteq A$ we can take $g(X) = f(X)$ i.e. we use image of $X$ under the function $f$ as our function $g$ from $\mathscr{P}(A)$ to $\mathscr{P}(B)$. *(I'm not sure about that. May be I could use the symbol $f$ without introducing $g$ but I wanted to avoid using $f$ both for the function from $A$ to $B$ and for the function from $\mathscr{P}(A)$ to $\mathscr{P}(B)$)*

Now we should check that $g$ is one-to-one and onto.

1. Let's assume $X_1\in \mathscr{P}(A)$ and $X_2\in \mathscr{P}(A)$, $X_1\neq X_2$ but $g(X_1) = g(X_2) = Y \in \mathscr{P}(B)$. Since $X_1 \neq X_2$ let's choose $x\in X_1$ but $x\notin X_2$. If $X_1 \subseteq X_2$ we should switch the subscripts before choosing $x$. Let $y = f(x)$ and $y\in Y$ since $g(X_1) = Y$. But then there is some $x' \in X_2$ so that $f(x') = y$. But $f$ is one-to-one so $x = x'$ and  $x\in X_2$. Contradiction. Using this steps to be more rigorous it's easy to proove that $X_1 \subseteq X_2$ and $X_2 \subseteq X_1$. So $g$ is one-to-one.
2. Let's choose any set $Y \in \mathscr{P}(B)$. Since $f$ is onto then for any nonempty set $Y$ there is nonempty set $X\in \mathscr{P}(A)$ so that $g(X) = Y$. And for empty set $Y$ we have $g(\varnothing) = Y$. So $g$ is onto.

Does this proof clear? May be it should be improved.

Comment: It seems well to me, I would not correct anything.

Comment: Since $g$ is so clearly derived from $f$, I might have chosen to call it $f_*$ or $f_{\mathscr P}$ or something. But that's a purely aesthetic choice.

Comment: Is $\sim$ an equivalent relation? If so, what are the domain and range of this relation?

Comment: When proving a function is one-to-one, there's no need for a proof by contradiction; rather, start by assuming that $g(X_1)=g(X_2)$ and then directly prove that $X_1=X_2$—that verifies the (contrapositive of the) definition of one-to-one.

Comment: Regarding the proof that $g$ is onto, I find the current version circular. Why should we believe that there exists such a set $g$ when that's what we're trying to prove? One should write down a specific set $X$ (in terms of $Y$ and $f$) and show that $g(X)=Y$. Also there shouldn't be a need to make the empty set a special case.

Comment: @TranKhanh Here $\sim$ is being used to denote the equicardinality relation. It's not entirely standard (in my experience), but definitely not unheard of, especially in older work.

Comment: @GregMartin How is the surjectivity proof circular? f sends elements of A to elements of B, whereas g sends subsets of A to subsets of B. OP seems to have used the surjectivity of f to deduce surjectivity of g to me. I agree on the empty set part though.

Comment: @Divide1918 The argument consists of the phrase "Since $f$ is onto then" followed by the exact statement the argument is supposed to prove.

Comment: @GregMartin The statement directly follows from the fact f is onto.

Comment: Of course it follows, but *it needs a proof* in the context of proving that exact statement. What is the set $X$? It should be written down and verified.